# answer_url error while creating a wiki application in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi I am trying to integrate a wiki to a social networking website that I am created. I am still in the process of creating wiki before integrating it. So I first made:

`rails generate scaffold Question title:string body:text`

`rails generate scaffold Answer question_id:integer body:text`

My model files for each are as follows:

question.rb:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :answers
     validates :title, :presence => true 
     validates :body, :presence => true
end
```

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :question
     validates :question_id, :presence => true 
     validates :body, :presence => true
end
```

My controller files are as follows:

question_controller.rb:

```
 class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
     def index
        @questions = Question.all

           respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @questions }
    end
 end

    def show
          @question = Question.find(params[:id])

          respond_to do |format|
              format.html # show.html.erb
              format.json { render :json => @question }
          end
    end

    def new
           @question = Question.new

           respond_to do |format|
                format.html # new.html.erb
                format.json { render :json => @question }
          end
   end

   def edit
          @question = Question.find(params[:id])
   end


  def create
         @question = Question.new(params[:question])

         respond_to do |format|
              if @question.save
                  format.html { redirect_to @question, :notice => 'Question was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @question, :status => :created, :location => @question }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @question.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
  end

    def update
       @question = Question.find(params[:id])

       respond_to do |format|
           if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
              format.html { redirect_to @question, :notice => 'Question was successfully updated.' }
               format.json { head :ok }
           else
                format.html { render :action => "edit" }
                format.json { render :json => @question.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
           end
       end
    end
  end
```

answer_controller.rb is:

```
   class AnswersController < ApplicationController

      def new
        @answer = Answer.new

        respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render :json => @answer }
      end
   end

   def create
         @question = Question.find(params[:question_id]) 
         @answer = @question.answers.create!(params[:answer])

         respond_to do |format|
            if @answer.save
                format.html { redirect_to @answer, :notice => 'Answer was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :json => @answer, :status => :created, :location => @answer }
            else
                format.html { render :action => "new" }
                format.json { render :json => @answer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
       end
   end
```

Finally my routes file is:

routes.rb

```
 SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

     resources :questions do 
         resources :answers
     end
 ........................
```

The view files for question is:

show.html.erb:

```
     <%= render :partial => @question %>
     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %> |
     <%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>
     <br/> <br/>
     <h4>Answers</h4> 
     <div id="answers">
     <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %> 
    <%= div_for answer do %>
       <p> <strong>
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(answer.created_at) %>
       </strong>
       <br /> <%= h(answer.body) %> 
       </p>
    <% end %> 
     <% end %>
   </div>

   <%= form_for [@question, Answer.new] do |f| %> 
   <p>
   <%= f.label :body, "New Answer" %>
   <br />
   <%= f.text_area :body %> 
    </p>
   <p><%= f.submit "Add Answer" %></p> 
  <% end %>
```

When I try to create a new Question is doesn't give me any error. When I open the already created questions it displays the content but I am having an error when I am trying add a new answer to the already created question it gives me the following error:

```
   **NoMethodError in AnswersController#create**

        undefined method `answer_url' for #<AnswersController:0x103273c70>
        app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:18:in `create'
        app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:16:in `create'

   **Request**

   **Parameters:**

        {"question_id"=>"1",
         "commit"=>"Add Answer",
         "authenticity_token"=>"ttPniOSpgGDMRu7+OJW2eS5rJMV/+ivVNOeI+rWOUPY=",
         "utf8"=>"\342\234\223",
         "answer"=>{"body"=>"ok!"}}
```

So what it is doing is it is adding the answer to the question but it is for some reason not redirecting it to the same question page. When I reload the same question I find the new answer that was added. So could you please help me out as to why this is happening? I need to be able to add an answer to the post and the answer should appear without reloading or giving me above error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `redirect_to @answer`

Replace with `redirect_to @question`

Beware of `:location => @answer` too.

Comment: What did you mean by beware of :location => @answer?!

Comment: This will look for the same unexisting path as far as I recall